# How to frame a query which will fetch all the tables from DB and have to set one particular column value to 0

Tags: db2

I have a requirement to frame a query which will fetch all the tables from database and to reset one column value to `0`. 
The problem is tables will be addeEd dynamically and there is no fixed number of tables. For example at preset I have some 30 tables and the number will be increased.

I used the below query to fetch all the existing tables from the DB:

```
SELECT TABNAME from SYSCAT.TABLES where TABSCHEMA = 'ABC';
```

I also framed the update query to reset the values to `0`

```
UPDATE ABC.CMP7_CALL_RECORD_EVENT SET CMP7_COUNT = 0 ;
```

Now by using both queries how can I frame a query which will  fetch all the tables from the DB and reset the particular column value to `0` from each table?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to have everything in a single query, a procedure or do you need help to generate a script to perform that task? For the latter there are already answers here on SO.

Comment: Hello henrik thanks for the response , i like to have everything in a single query .

Comment: Ok, that is not possible because you can only update a single table, see here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001022.html

Comment: thanks for the reference link . is it possible with a procedure ?

Comment: @SrikanthReddy, yes your options are to use a script (in your preferred Db2-friendly scripting language), or use an SQL-stored-procedure, or simply use a  compound-SQL block.

Comment: @mao thank you very much ! i will try stored- procedure

Answer (score 0):

You could try a compound SQL block as suggested my @mao

```
BEGIN FOR D AS 
     SELECT 'UPDATE "' || TABSCHEMA ||'"."'|| TABNAME 
     || '" SET CMP7_COUNT = 0 WHERE CMP7_COUNT IS DISTINCT FROM 0' AS STMT
     FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE COLNAME = 'CMP7_COUNT'
     DO      
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE D.STMT;
     END FOR;
END
```

you might want to add a `COMMIT` after each update if you have a a lot of tables/rows to update. If you needed that then the cursor needs to be `WITH HOLD`. I.e.

```
BEGIN FOR D AS cur CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR 
     SELECT 'UPDATE "' || TABSCHEMA ||'"."'|| TABNAME 
     || '" SET CMP7_COUNT = 0 WHERE CMP7_COUNT IS DISTINCT FROM 0' AS STMT
      FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE COLNAME = 'CMP7_COUNT'
      DO      
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE D.STMT;
          COMMIT;
      END FOR;
END
```

P.S. you need to use a statement terminator other than `;` when running the above examples